# Domain Model Class Diagram - What classes should i add?

Tags: android, uml, class-diagram, domain-model

I must create Domain Model Class Diagram of my Android application.

The big problem is that my android app has arround 40-50 classes. Many of them are doing similar things. For example `ImageMultiChoiceListener, VideoMultiChoiceListener` or `PhotoItem, VideoItem` or `CustomPhotoAdapter, CustomVideoAdapter` etc...

I can't add all these classes to one class diagram. It is chaos!

So, i guess im doing something wrong and i put em all in 1 class diagram.

Here comes the question: What classes should i add in diagram? `everything` or `only importants`???. If `only importants`, what we mean with that? which ones?

Answer (score 2):

Again, it depends. There is no point in creating wall papers except for putting them on a wall. If you want to eat an elephant you do it not in one piece but in small slices. In such cases you should try to find sub-domains where classes belong to each other. Each sub-domain can be packaged and described with an individual diagram. Then for an overview just show the sub-domain packages and how they depend on each other.

When following the above approach you will likely find certain classes which have move connectors and build the center for each sub-domain. So make them prominent by putting them in the center. Eventually use colors and/or border thickness for highlighting. But all of your classes shall appear in at least one diagram. That means you may well have others that appear in more than one diagram. Eventually you will need a couple of shifts to find the right sub-domain cut.

When you are done you can put all sub-domain diagrams in a big one and print a wall paper. But only if you have the money for the A0 printer ;-)

Comment: I agree. This comment is just to underscore the same.
1.: All classes _and all relations_ shall appear in at least one diagram.
2.: A diagram showing classes for package X, may also show related classes from other packages.
3.: Personally, I prefer to give every package its own color and all classes have the same color as their packages. By doing so, you can easily identify the classes that don't belong to package X in a diagram focusing on classes in package X.

Answer (score 0):

The word "domain model" usually means a class model of entities from the *problem domain* (business domain). 'PhotoItem' and 'VideoItem' are probably classes derived from the problem domain, but 'ImageMultiChoiceListener' is not something you will find in the real world. The domain model class diagram will include real-world classes like PhotoItem and VideoItem and the relationships among these classes, but not the technical classes like ImageMultiChoiceListener.